# Does before(:context) scoping go into children contexts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In the following code sample, is the **before block** run before both the parent and the subcontexts and therefore 3 times?

Or just the parent and therefore 1 time?

i.e. how deep does scope go?

```
    describe "my spec class" do

       before(:context) do
           do stuff
       end



       context "parent context" do
          context "subcontext" do
            stuff...
          end 

         context "subcontext" do
            stuff.....
         end
       end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should run once before all examples in the group. And accessible by the nested contexts. 
A couple links worth checking out:

[Nested Context](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#nested-examples-have-access-to-state-set-in-outer-%60before(:context)%60)

[Before and After hooks](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks)

Comment: I looked at those before I posted but they weren't much help with my issue. 

So you're saying it should run once before all examples...even nested contexts?