# RSpec before blocks not being called before contexts or describes

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, tdd

Given the following code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) { puts 'before all' }
  config.before(:suite) { puts 'before suite'}
  config.before(:context) { puts 'before context'}
  config.before(:each) { puts 'before each'}
end


RSpec.describe "SomeClass" do
  it 'matches some regex' do
    puts 'in first it block'
    expect('some string').to match(/.*/)
  end

  describe 'some group of tests' do
    puts 'in some group'

    context 'when some thing happens' do
      puts 'in context'
      it 'does something' do
        expect(true).to be_truthy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I would expect the following output:

```
before suite
before all
before context
before each
in some group
in context
in first it block
.before each
```

But instead I get:

```
in some group
in context
before suite
before all
before context
before each
in first it block
.before each
```

Meaning that `context` or `describe` gets run before any before configuration I've set up.

I expect it to be the first output because of what I've read [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-%60before(:context)%60-block-in-example-group) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881459/does-beforecontext-scoping-go-into-children-contexts).

**What do I do when I absolutely need code to run before absolutely anything else in the test files? Including (nested) context or describes? And why doesn't it work the way I expect?**

Note: I see the same behavior when I include the `before :something` statements within the scope of the uppermost `describe`.

(This question is similar to [this question](http://Note:%20I%20see%20the%20same%20behavior%20when%20I%20include%20the%20%60before%20:something%60%20statements%20within%20the%20scope%20of%20the%20uppermost%20%60describe%60.), but not the same.  I would like to know why my tests are running this way and what the proper RSpec convention is to run a piece of code before absolutely anything else.)

Version info:

```
RSpec 3.6
  - rspec-core 3.6.0
  - rspec-expectations 3.6.0
  - rspec-mocks 3.6.0
  - rspec-support 3.6.0
```

**UPDATE:**

It may be helpful to know some context:  I'm writing selenium front end automated tests using the `selenium-webdriver` gem.  Before any and all `it` blocks run, I need to call a function called `navigate()` (in order to take me to the web page I'm writing the tests for, this function takes about 30 seconds to run because it takes me through two login pages before it gets to where it needs to go) to be called and complete before anything else happens. In my RSpec file I'm using `before` blocks in an attempt to make this happen, however rspec keeps running tests before the `before` blocks, and failing.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to put `puts "in some group"` and `puts "in context"` into `before(:all)` blocks, then the output is closer to what you're expecting.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) { puts 'before all' }
  config.before(:suite) { puts 'before suite'}
  config.before(:context) { puts 'before context'}
  config.before(:each) { puts 'before each'}
end


RSpec.describe "SomeClass" do
  it 'matches some regex' do
    puts 'in first it block'
    expect('some string').to match(/.*/)
  end

  describe 'some group of tests' do
    before(:all) { puts 'in some group' }

    context 'when some thing happens' do
      before(:all) { puts 'in context' }

      it 'does something' do
        expect(true).to be_truthy
      end
    end
  end
end
```

outputs

```
before suite
before all
before context
before each
in first it block
.in some group
in context
before each
.
```

or, if you did `before(:each)` you would get

```
before suite
before all
before context
before each
in first it block
.before each
in some group
in context
.
```

The reason for the current output is your `puts` statements for "in some group" and "in context" are being executed when the file is being parsed, not waiting for RSpec at all. If we gave a different example, without Rspec in the mix, imagine we had a file with just

```
class SomeClass
  puts "in class"

  def do_something
    puts "doing something"
  end
end
```

if we load that file into an `irb` session or run it on the command line with `ruby`, we would see "in class" output in the console even though we haven't done anything with that class.

Comment: hopefully I explained that well enough, if you're still confused by anything let me know and I can take another stab at it.

Comment: I understand.  Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: So, I understand why it's behaving the way it's behaving.  My original question though is: "What do I do when I absolutely need code to run before absolutely anything else in the test files? Including (nested) context or describes?"  Do I just need to have a before :all/:each block within every sub-context?  I want to just be able to call one piece of code before any it block runs, ever.